# OAuthException 2500 when calling any FB api from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

Problem: **I keep getting the following error from Facebook**:

```
Code: 2500
Message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
Type: OAuthException
```

The call I made is:

```
Function TestResponse(response) {….}
FB.api(‘/me’, TestResponse);
```

I used the Facebook Application template for MVC4.  On the server side I’m able to do everything, but from the client side, using JavaScript, I can’t make any calls.  On the server side I store the authorization token and I’ve tried pulling it back and passing it to Facebook as follows:

```
var parameters = { access_token: $('#AccessToken').val() };
FB.api('/me', parameters, TestResponse);
```

Returns the same thing.    This code is called from as part of my $(document).ready setup.  The layout page has all of the fb init stuff.

As mentioned: from C# I can make calls to the facebook API and things work, but I’d really like to do most of the work from JavaScript to avoid having an extra round trip thrown in to my application.

also: I've tried calling getLoginStatus but it never provides a response.

Comment: Have you looked at your generated source to see if your `access_token` is present, and checked it with the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to be sure it is valid?

Comment: @cpilko - yes, the token is there.  Am I not passing it correctly or is there something else I need to do first?

Comment: Do you get a valid access token in the console when you `console.log($('#AccessToken').val())`?

Comment: Not sure if I've actually solved this but here is what I did:  FB.api('/me?access_token=' + $('#AccessToken').val()....  FB now responds with an object instead of the exception.  I'd love for somebody who actually know what they're doing to provide me some schoolin. :)

Answer (score -1):

a short workaround should using `FB.api('userId');` instead.

Comment: I'm really sorry - but how does that address the problem I'm having?

Comment: 'me' looks for a valid facebook session whereas 'facebook user_id' does not